# How to place Regex in once place (at the top of my page) and use it anywhere in my View page

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc

I need help please. One told me that I can place my Regex at the top of my page and use it anywhere in my view page;
cause so far I'm doing as the below for every single place I need to remove HTML tag.

```
                                <div class="arsenalTeam">
                                    <div class="titleTeam">TEAM DETAIL</div>
                                    <hr class="my-4">
                                    @{
                                        String descript = Regex.Replace(item.TeamDescription, @"<[^>]*>", String.Empty);
                                        <div class="descriptionTeam"> @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => descript)</div>                                     
                                    }
                                </div>
```

Comment: There are many [examples](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/web-pages/overview/getting-started/introducing-razor-syntax-c) of this on the web.